# Qualify group by in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, teradata

I've started using `qualify` in BigQuery and I have an issue with the `group by` operator.

This works correctly (although I have to put `where true` which is a bit weird):

```sql
WITH Produce AS (
  SELECT 'Kale' as product, 51 as sales, 'Q1' as quarter UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 23, 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 45, 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 3, 'Q4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 77, 'Q1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 0, 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 25, 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 2, 'Q4')
SELECT *
FROM Produce
WHERE true QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY quarter  DESC) <= 1
```

But this doesn't work:

```sql
WITH Produce AS (
  SELECT 'Kale' as product, 51 as sales, 'Q1' as quarter UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 23, 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 45, 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 3, 'Q4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 77, 'Q1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 0, 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 25, 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 2, 'Q4')
SELECT product, count(*)
FROM Produce
WHERE true QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY quarter  DESC) <= 1
group by 1
```

Am I doing something wrong? The error thrown is

```
Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword GROUP at [13:1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qualify` is expected to be after `group by`:

```
WITH Produce AS (
  SELECT 'Kale' as product, 51 as sales, 'Q1' as quarter UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 23, 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 45, 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 3, 'Q4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 77, 'Q1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 0, 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 25, 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 2, 'Q4')
SELECT product, count(*)
FROM Produce
WHERE true 
group by product, quarter
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY quarter  DESC) <= 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the clauses in the wrong order.  The ordering for what you care about is:

```
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
QUALIFY
```

So, try this:

```
SELECT product, count(*)
FROM Produce
WHERE true 
GROUP BY 1
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY quarter DESC) <= 1
```

Comment: With your query I get: `Window ORDER BY expression references column quarter which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [14:52]`

Comment: group by should by `group by product, quarter` instead apparently

Comment: @DavidMasip . . . In that case, you cannot logic do what you are asking for.  *Perhaps* `quarter` in the `group by` does what you want.  I admit to focusing on the question you **asked** by putting the `qualify` in the right place.  You don't describe the logic you actually want.

Comment: yeah, I just wanted to have a product count

Comment: @DavidMasip . . . Not clear that quarter has anything to do with that.